# StringField is defined as unique, but duplicates are saved silently

Tags: django, mongodb, unique, mongoengine

I defined a simple Document, like this:

```
class Company(Document):
    screen_name = StringField(max_length=100, required=True, unique=True)
    official_name = StringField(required=False)

    meta = {
        'indexes': [{'fields': 'screen_name', 'unique': True}]
    }
```

but when I am writing a test

```
@use_tdb
def test_company3():
    """ test company2 """
    company = Company(screen_name='asdasd')
    company.save()
    company = Company(screen_name='asdasd')
    with nt.assert_raises(OperationError):
        company.save()
        pprint([(x.id, x.screen_name,) for x in Company.objects.all()])
```

It actually saves both of them. And I see in output:

```
[(ObjectId('4f719f915c121a21ad000003'), u'asdasd'),
 (ObjectId('4f719f915c121a21ad000004'), u'asdasd')]
```

Any ideas, what I've done wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is may be required drop_collection.

```
def test_company3():
    """ test company2 """
    Company.drop_collection()
    company = Company(screen_name='asdasd')
    company.save()
    company = Company(screen_name='asdasd')
    with nt.assert_raises(OperationError):
        company.save()
    pprint([(x.id, x.screen_name,) for x in Company.objects.all()])
```

See this tests. Mongoengine is all tests is passed. 
https://github.com/hmarr/mongoengine/blob/master/tests/document.py#L875

Mongoengine team Recently relaeed 0.6.3.

Comment: Thanks, @Ankhaa, it works! But I got a little bit confused. On each test I already had my use_tdb decorator which drops all collections (except 'system.indexes') before and after each test. But this did not help.  And even when I dropped test db manually from mongo shell, problem was still remaining. I can't get it! db.dropDatabase() do not permanently remove db and on next run of tests mongodb picks old indexes?

Comment: Yes. Old indexes is complicated and confusing. Did you see mongoengine tests. All test start first command is drop_collection. That is only understand for mongoengine and mongodb. not use in Production :).

Comment: Yup, got it! And I have another question. Is there any elegant way to rebuild indexes for already existing collection(in development or production db) except QuerySet._reset_already_indexed(document=Company)?

Comment: In runtime that very danger!. I am not sure about this. Not use that case that functions. I use in mongoshell and db.collection.dropIndexes() and create indexes manualy. 
But i still learned Mongodb.